# Task.Run travando dentro de um "tick" (Forms.Timer)

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, asynctask, timer

Em minha aplicação, criei um "Timer" (System.Windows.Forms) que é executado a cada 1 segundo. No evento "tick", coloquei um await Task.Run.

Por algum motivo o tick para de executar depois de um tempo (pois ele não imprime a data e hora no console).

```
Class x {
    public Timer timer {get; set;}

    public void f()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.tick);
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.status = ProcessoStatus.TRABALHANDO;
        this.timer.Stop();

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => this.processo());
        }
        catch
        {}

        this.timer.Start();
        this.status = ProcessoStatus.OCIOSO;
    }

    public void processo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, se tu usar um `System.Threading.Timer` não dá o mesmo efeito? Nesse caso ele já faria em outra `thread` até.

Comment: Ele chega a executar algumas vezes ou trava na primeira?

Comment: Define "para de executar". Executa uma vez até ao fim e depois nao executa mais? Encrava (deadlock) na primeira execução? Em que linha? Se remover o `await Task.Run` o problema desaparece? O que faz o método `processo()`? Esta pergunta necessita de mais detalhes.

Comment: A cada 1 segundo, o tick "escreve" a data e hora em um listview (no exemplo eu coloquei no console para exemplificar). Se eu deixar o programa aberto por um tempo (indeterminado) a hora não fica mudando no listview.

Quanto a usar o Threading.Timer, eu não sei. Posso pesquisar. Eu preciso que o timer apenas execute quando o método "processo" termine. Por isso eu coloquei um "start"/"stop" ali. Para ele não sobrepor as execuções.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entendo o que está tentando fazer, porém o `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` simplesmente não foi criado para isso. Essa citação, direto do MSDN:

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

Ou, em português:

> O componente do Windows Forms Timer é single-threaded e está limitado a uma precisão de 55 milissegundos. Se precisar de um timer de vários threads com maior precisão, use o Timer classe na namespace System.Timers.

Nesse caso, sugiro que utilize o `System.Timers.Timer`, sendo possível usá-lo tanto em WinForms quanto qualquer outro instante.